# Avestan grammar help: Azə̄m θβąm vaēnami?

Tags: avestan

I am constructing Avestan sentence for a language research paper on Iranian languages

Are these conclusions correct

Subject

> Azə̄m = I {singular 1st person, nominative)

Object

> θβąm = you (singular 2nd person, accusative)

Verb

> vaēnāmi = observe/see (present, 1st person, singular indicative active)

So that it means:
"I see you"

Comment: I have suggested some corrections.

Comment: And, for the pleasure of the "close" voters, I have addressed some general linguistic issues in my reply.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, this is correct, with some provisos. azə̄m is Old (Gathic) Avestan; in Young Avestan you would have azəm (with short ə), but if you use the former then the whole phrase would need to be OAv, hence with vaēnā or vaēnāmī (both with long final vowel). If you want to have it in YAv the verb would be vaēnāmi (as in the body of your question, not vaēnami as in your title).

A different question is whether this is stylistically adequate. In Avestan, as in other “pro-drop” languages, you would not normally use the nominative pronoun (here azə̄m or azəm) with a verb in the 1st person singular, unless it is specially emphasized. For the 2nd person singular pronoun you would normally use not the stressed pronoun θβąm, but the enclitic θβā. So the whole phrase would be (assuming YAv) θβā vaēnāmi.

Comment: Thank you so much @fdb this share many simalarities with other Eastern Iranian Langauges e.g. Wakhi Wuz tau winəm (source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9hNKd8JOqc)